# Nested table in oracle giving error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am not able to create a nested table. I executed the following commands:

```
create or replace type address_ty as object(
    street nvarchar2(15),
    city nvarchar2(15),
    district nvarchar2(15));

create or replace type name_ty as object(
    name nvarchar2(15),
    address address_ty);

create or replace type dependent_ty as object(
    relation nvarchar2(15),
    name name_ty,
    age number);

create or replace type dependent_list as table of dependent_ty;

create or replace type employee_info_ty as object(
    emp_id nvarchar(15),
    name name_ty,
    salary nvarchar(15),
    dept_id nvarchar(15),
    dependents dependent_list);
```

When I create a table it gives an error:

```
create table employee_info of employee_info_ty OIDINDEX OID_EMPLOYEE_INFO
nested table dependent store as dependent_ty;

SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last type declaration is invalid:

```sql
create or replace type employee_info_ty as object(
    emp_id nvarchar(15),
    name name_ty,
    salary nvarchar(15),
    dept_id nvarchar(15),
    dependents dependent_list);
/

Warning: Type created with compilation errors.

show errors

Errors for TYPE EMPLOYEE_INFO_TY:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
2/12     PLS-00201: identifier 'NVARCHAR' must be declared
```

If that's changed to use `nvarchar2` then the `invalid datatype` error against `employee_info_ty` goes away but is replaced with another error:

```sql
create or replace type employee_info_ty as object(
    emp_id nvarchar2(15),
    name name_ty,
    salary nvarchar2(15),
    dept_id nvarchar2(15),
    dependents dependent_list);
/

Type created.

create table employee_info of employee_info_ty OIDINDEX OID_EMPLOYEE_INFO
nested table dependents store as dependent_ty;

nested table dependent store as dependent_ty
             *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

... which is because you called the nested table `dependents` in the type definition but `dependent` here. You also can't re-use `dependent_ty` for the `store as` clause as that's an object type you just created; you'd get an ORA-00955. This works:

```sql
create table employee_info of employee_info_ty OIDINDEX OID_EMPLOYEE_INFO
nested table dependents store as dependents_tab;

Table created.
```

---

From question in comments, if you populate a row like:

```
insert into employee_info values (
    employee_info_ty('1', name_ty('Joe Bloggs',
            address_ty('1 Main Street', 'Omaha', 'Nebraska')),
        '20000', '2', dependent_list(dependent_ty('Daughter',
            name_ty('Emily Bloggs',
                address_ty('1 Main Street', 'Omaha', 'Nebraska')),
            '14')
        )
    )
);
```

You can select immediate attributes like:

```
select e.emp_id, e.name.name
from employee_info e;

EMP_ID          NAME.NAME
--------------- ---------------
1               Joe Bloggs
```

And nested attributes like:

```
select d.relation, d.name.name, d.age
from the(select e.dependents from employee_info e where emp_id = '1') d;

RELATION        NAME.NAME              AGE
--------------- --------------- ----------
Daughter        Emily Bloggs            14
```

I imagine you're manipulating these in PL/SQL, but the principle is the same.

Not sure why you're storing `emp_id` and `salary` as strings though.

Comment: The table employee_info is created but how can i access the attributes of dependents.I can access other objects attributes.

Comment: @AbhiruchiSharma - added an insert/select example.